# How to create kubernates cluster using azure python sdk

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python

I'm not able to get proper documentation for this on [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api). I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-containerservice/azure.mgmt.containerservice.v2018_03_31.operations.managedclustersoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-resource-group-name--resource-name--parameters--custom-headers-none--raw-false--polling-true----operation-config-) but not able to completely understand how to instantiate all the parameters. Is there better documentation/samples available for azure python SDKs?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the SDK tests as a sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/containerservice/azure-mgmt-containerservice/tests/test_mgmt_containerservice.py

```
container_services.create_or_update(
            resource_group.name,
            container_name,
            {
                'location': location,
                "orchestrator_profile": {
                    "orchestrator_type": "DCOS"
                },
                "master_profile": {
                    "count": 1,
                    "dns_prefix": "MasterPrefixTest",
                    "vm_size": ContainerServiceVMSizeTypes.standard_d2_v2
                },
                "agent_pool_profiles": [{
                    "name": "agentpool0",
                    "count": 3,
                    "vm_size": "Standard_A2_v2",
                    # "dns_prefix": "AgentPrefixTest" - Optional in latest version
                }],
                "linux_profile": {
                    "admin_username": "acslinuxadmin",
                    "ssh": {
                       "public_keys": [{
                            "key_data": "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAlj9UC6+57XWVu0fd6zqXa256EU9EZdoLGE3TqdZqu9fvUvLQOX2G0d5DmFhDCyTmWLQUx3/ONQ9RotYmHGymBIPQcpx43nnxsuihAILcpGZ5NjCj4IOYnmhdULxN4ti7k00S+udqokrRYpmwt0N4NA4VT9cN+7uJDL8Opqa1FYu0CT/RqSW+3aoQ0nfGj11axoxM37FuOMZ/c7mBSxvuI9NsDmcDQOUmPXjlgNlxrLzf6VcjxnJh4AO83zbyLok37mW/C7CuNK4WowjPO1Ix2kqRHRxBrzxYZ9xqZPc8GpFTw/dxJEYdJ3xlitbOoBoDgrL5gSITv6ESlNqjPk6kHQ== azureuser@linuxvm"
                       }]
                    }
                },
            },
        )
```